# Auditing entries in the SMTP Relay with gmail logs and BQ

Tags: google-bigquery, gmail, google-workspace

I have exported gmail logs to bigquery.

I have some third party IP addresses in our G Suite SMTP Relay whitelist:
https://support.google.com/a/answer/2956491?hl=en

Since the 3rd party can essentially send mail on behalf of any account in the domain, I would like to audit the IP's and the email address they are sending mail as.

I can't figure out the right fields from the schema to query.
https://support.google.com/a/answer/7230050?hl=en

Anyone done something similar?

Thanks!

Comment: Your question is too general, therefore I can only direct you to the BigQuery Schema docs. https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/schemas

Comment: You should update your question with one example of your exported gmail logs to BigQuery.